# how to Normalize the sql table in two tables or one detailed table

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot

I would like little help with my SQL normalization. I have a table with as follows:

```
tbl_code

Ucode, desc, code1, code2, code3
1      aa    1      1      1
2      bb    1      2      2
3      cc    1      1      1
```

Now I want to make this table to normalized as:

```
ucode, desc, code,  value
1      aa    code1  1     
2      bb    code1  1    
3      cc    code1  1
1      aa    code2  1
```

and so on...

How can I do this in SQL? Can someone please help me out?

Comment: This isn't normalization, it's unpivoting. Notmalizing this would require breaking it into *three* talbes, one for the `ucode/desc` pari, one for `code` and one for the values stored for each combination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet another option

```
Select A.UCode
      ,A.[Desc]
      ,B.*
 From tbl_code A
 Cross Apply (
               values ('code1',code1)
                     ,('code2',code2)
                     ,('code3',code3)
             ) B(code,value)
```

> **Updated - Dynamic without using Dynamic SQL**

```
Select A.Ucode
      ,A.[desc]
      ,C.*
 From  tbl_code A
 Cross Apply ( values (cast((Select A.* for XML RAW) as xml))) B(XMLData)
 Cross Apply (
                Select Code  = a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
                      ,Value = a.value('.','varchar(max)') 
                 From  B.XMLData.nodes('/row')  as C1(n)
                 Cross Apply C1.n.nodes('./@*') as C2(a)
                 Where a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') not in ('Ucode','desc')
                 -- {or you can use} Where a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') like 'code%'
             ) C
```

Comment: @tanay Happy it helped.

Comment: @tanay FYI - I prefer this approach over UNPIVOT because it allow for a bit more flexibility / control.

Comment: hi john can we any how automate the process for example if my nest table have only 2 code(code1,code2) or 5 code i ahve to edit the whole process over and if i have 35 or 50 codes its gonna me way to long code so based on the source file can we automate the process ?

Comment: @tanay see update/edit  -- This is a little less performant but it is dyanmic

Comment: @tanay  See it in action  http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=709da0d59c23f9892cfa9f53d91eb97f

Comment: hi john thank youfor the solution but the output is not getting the actual column name but instead _x0037_DR something like that aso can it be possible to get the actual field name only in the data without all this codes infornt of that just simple 4DR ,5DR like that

Comment: @tanay XML does not like attributes begining with non-alpha characters.  You would perform some sort of replace()

Comment: can we use this to populate  select column_name from information_schema.columns
 where table_name = 'FOOD BASICS' and column_name not in ( 'UPC','Cust  Code','DESCRIPTION','Banner')
order by ordinal_position  this gives me exactly what i need as a data but i dont know how i can use this to get what i need

Comment: @tanay Seems like you want DYNAMIC UNPIVOT

Comment: yes i linke dynamics pivot but the data i am gettin from your query is all gibrish something wrong with the source table. is it possible to auto feed column name as row. please help me out if you have any idea

Answer (score 0):

This should get you going, but you will probably end up with NULLs etc. to deal with in real life?

```
SELECT
    ucode,
    [desc],
    'code1' AS code,
    code1 AS [value]
FROM
    tbl_code
UNION ALL
SELECT
    ucode,
    [desc],
    'code2' AS code,
    code2 AS [value]
FROM
    tbl_code
UNION ALL
SELECT
    ucode,
    [desc],
    'code3' AS code,
    code3 AS [value]
FROM
    tbl_code;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNPIVOT like this:

```
SELECT distinct ucode, desc, code, value
FROM 
(
SELECT *
FROM tbl_code
) AS cp
UNPIVOT (value
FOR code IN (code1, code2, code3)) AS up
Order by code;
```

And the output will look like this:

[image]

Comment: hi can i use FOR code IN ("select statement here ")) AS up @@cas i am trying to get the columnname from the table tbl_code so i dont have to enter all the column name manually if i have large number of column name. is there any way please let me know asap i am really struglling with this. thank you.

Comment: Hi @tanay, no we have to specify each column name, this is similar to writing a case statement and specifying each case. I will try to research another way for large number of columns.